# Facebook link opens properly in web browser but not in native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

This is my code for opening a facebook link from my app:

```
 // Check to make sure user has Facebook app installed
    if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mobileUrl]]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mobileUrl]];

        NSLog(@"Mobile %@",mobileUrl);
    }
    // If not, open it in browser
    else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:challenge[@"actionUrl"]]];

        NSLog(@"Web %@",challenge[@"actionUrl"]);
    }
```

I have valid links for both cases.

Web link: https://www.facebook.com/gqbeerpb/posts/1431080253818425
App link: fb://post/1431079887151795_1431080253818425

But every time I try to open any link with a native app, I end up on my timeline.
When I comment out the code for opening it in an app, and open it in safari instead, I get navigated to the right page.

Comment: Where are you getting the fb://post/... url from?

Comment: I fetch them from the server

Comment: From which server? From Facebook? There's no publicized support for the fb://post/ custom scheme, so you should not expect it to work.